# Uncaught TypeError: "#myForm".submit is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have been struggling with this problem for over 2 hours now, and i know there are recent threads about this, but theres absolutely zero help for me there.
First i can say, my input button does **not** have name="submit" or some other attribute named submit.

Would appreciate if someone could tell me whats wrong here.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/jquery.form/3.50/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="formarea">
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myForm">
      <select name="type" id="selectedoption">
          <option value="">Välj typ här</option>
          <option value="photo">Foto</option>
          <option value="video">Video</option>
          <option value="audio">Ljud</option>

      </select>
      <input id="block" type="file">

      Titel
      <input type="text" name="title">
      <input type="submit" value="Spara media" class="btn">
    </form>
    <div id="bararea">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="percent"></div>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script src="test.js"> </script>
```

JS

```
    // När man skickar iväg formuläret (klickat på knappen "Spara media")
("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    alert("hello");
  // Förhindrar att vi skickas iväg till en ny sida (standardhändelsen)
  e.preventDefault();
  // Hämtar formulärsdata (värde från drop-down menyn, samt filen)
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  // Gör ett ajax-anrop
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("action"), // Till adressen "server.php"
    type: $(this).attr("method"), // Med metoden "post"
    data: formData, // Vår data vi skickar med
    dataType: "JSON", // Hur vi ska tolka den data vi får tillbaka (som JSON)
    cache: false, // Vi tillåter inte att webbläsaren att cacha några resultat
    contentType: false, // Vi vill inte att jQuery ska bestämma hur vårt innehåll ska tolkas
    processData: false // Vi tillåter inte att jQuery att processa vår data (som strängar)
  }).done(function (data) {
    // Om vi får ett lyckat svar
    console.log(data);
        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
        alert("Upload completed");
  }).fail(function(data){
    // Om vi får ett misslyckat svar
    alert("Upload failed");
    console.log(data);});
});
$.getJSON('https://ddwap.mah.se//server.php?action=getMedia&type=photo', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

I cant understand why my function doesnt load when im pushing the button..

Comment: Missing $ sign.

Comment: $("#myForm").submit(

Answer (score -1):

I figured out im missing the $... Im going to sleep now. Sorry

Comment: Better, You may delete the post instead.